# convert a string to unsigned long int of a given base: generic algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, compilation, driver, strtoul

As part of compiling proprietary driver code, I am forced remove inclusion of `<stdlib.h>` to address type conflicts arising with kernel include files. The last mile in getting the code compiled and linked successfully seems to be to replace the C standard library function `strtoul()` with a hand coded method, so that the dependency on `<stdlib.h>` can be completely removed. But the catch is that the hand written code should address all the bases between 0 and 16 (inclusive) for conversion.

Can anyone suggest a generic algorithm to meet this requirement?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: There are many cases for full `strtoul()` functionality.  I recommend whatever you code, consider [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Vinod, `strtoul()` handles bases 2-36 (and 0).  You want _all the bases between 0 and 16_.  What other differences are OK?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was originally thinking of replacing strtoul() with kstrtoul() which handles only up to base 16....but ideally I would want all the bases supported by strtoul()...

Comment: Vinod, there is the case of `base == 0` steering to bases 8,10, or 16.  `errno` setting and value capping on out of range.  Leading `+,-` concerns and  `unsigned long` as 32, 64, ... size.  Optional `0x` on base 16 to handle.  There is `char **endptr` to handle especially with odd cases like `"0x"`.   The leading white-space is _locale_ sensitive.  I suspect you do not want a true `strtoul()` equivalent - but a _light_ one as already answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Take the string and base as parameters.  Start with a sum of 0.  Then for each character in the string going left to right:

- If it's a digit, convert to a value between 0 and 9
- If it's a letter (A-F or a-f), convert to a value between 10 and 16
- Multiply the current sum by the base, then add the value to the sum.